# Why is Paypal Standard not visible in Germany?

Tags: paypal, ce-1.9.0.1

If you set your `Merchant Country` to Germany the payment method Paypal `Website Payments Standard` is hidden in Magento ce-1.9.

Does anyone know why?

Some people say it's old and should not be used. But it is still advertised on [Magento Paypal page](http://magento.com/paypal/overview). Anyway if it's so old to be used why only Germany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve got the same problem. It´s a simple bug (my view).

1. Open up the tabs `Merchant Location` and `PayPal Payment Solution` in `Payment Methods`.
2. Change your `location` to `Austria` -> `PayPal Standard` appears. Save this configuration.
3. After that configure or set `PayPal standard` to yes/`active` -> save.
4. Change your `location` to `Germany` -> save.

Here we go: PayPal Standard for Germany!